# Search in Array makes browser crash

Tags: javascript, arrays, crash

Basically i´m getting data from two external sources and i wish to compare both.

First i´m getting data from a XML using Ajax and put it in a Array inside a Array:

```
var Array1 = []; //outside Ajax
...
var valueToPush = new Array();
valueToPush[0] = zz;
valueToPush[1] = aa;
Array1.push(valueToPush);
```

Then i´m getting a post from a PHP file that i scrapped from a HTML file, meanwhile i´m trying to compare both data from XML and from the scrapped HTML (using date time), also using a if statement to limit the search:

```
if (lng < (-18)) {

for(var i=0, len = Array1.length; i<len; i++) {

var date1 = Array1[i][1];

if (date2 == date1) {

alert("equal");
}

else {
//do something else
}
}
}
```

Well Firefox starts getting >1GB of Ram and the browser crash (sometimes i can stop the script). The problem (i think) is in the "for(var i=0, len = Array1.length; i

Anyone can point me out a solution?

Thanks

Edit: Live version of the site crashing. Removing from 435-449..resolves the issue of crashing, but doesnt compare data.
http://preview.tinyurl.com/mf9g9fq

**Edit2**: Following the comments, i edited the code to a much simpler version. It has two tables, one return the events from the scrapped HTML "if long < 18", the other table return the events "long > 18". Uncommenting 183 - 200 will make the browser crash. Notice after uncommenting, in the first table it will repeat infinitely the first result "if long < 18".

Working but commented - http://preview.tinyurl.com/mf9g9fq

Crashing uncommented - http://preview.tinyurl.com/m59p4wf

**Edit3**
Following *Crazy Train* user suggestion, i replaced a *i* with another letter ex *j* in a *for*, and it solved my problem! Explanation of the cause of this is in the below comments. Thanks *Crazy Train*!

Comment: How large is the file you are getting info from? and what's the length of Array1?

Comment: Whatever the issue is, you've left it out of the question.

Comment: The lenght of Array1 is "60". The scrapped Html with the If statement, should have around 70. But in some months i can get much more results than "60" or "70". Everything works great, but when i add the "for" followed by the "if", it crashes.

Comment: ...and please do take the time to indent your code cleanly when posting a question.

Comment: Whatever the issue is, you've left it out of the question.

Comment: Ok. Relatively new to this world (programming), so i dont understand well whats important or not to include here. Heres a live version of the site crashing (if you stop the script, you will notice a massive incorrect markers placed in the same location, but removing the for+if, everything works great.). http://preview.tinyurl.com/mf9g9fq

Comment: A link to the page with the code causing the crash commented out would be much more useful.

Comment: I couldn't even get the page to render, and you have a thousand things going on in that page.  The code you posted is not the reason this is crashing.  A good developer would isolate parts of the application until you find the part that has the issue, which you can then isolate further.  I recommend you create a simple demo of your problem with the crash without including everything.

Comment: I added two simpler codes, one causes the crash, the other works ok.

Comment: That's better. First, when debugging, what you need to do is eliminate chunks of code to eliminate them. That's what you did by commenting out the `for` loop, but you should have continued to do that. Eventually you'd have reduced it to a smaller bit of code that would have revealed the problem. Or if you still didn't know the issue, it would have been small enough to comfortably post in your question. My point is that you need to go through these basic debugging steps, and provide a working example of the problem in your question. The little bit of code you gave didn't accomplish that.

Comment: ...but finally, your problem is that you have your `for` loop inside another `for` loop, and both loops are using the `i` variable as the counter. So when you get to the inner `for` loop *(the one causing the problem)*, you're resetting `i` to `0`, and incrementing it to some value less than the boundary of the outer loop, so that loop never reaches its boundary, and never stops. Change your variable to `j` or something for the inner loop.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Crazy Train, debugging is really a important part, but in the "giant" original code was really hard to understand where the problem should be..so reducing it helps a lot. I followed your suggestion and changed  a "i" with "j" or something, and now the problem is solved! I really appreciate!